# How to merge rows into single column by grouping the same variable in R language

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a data frame

```
type   function   class
A      AXX        AYY
A      AZZ        AUU
B      BXX        BYY
B      BUU        BHH
```

I want to transform them into

```
type   function   class   type    function  class  
A      AXX        AYY     A      AZZ        AUU
B      BXX        BYY     B      BUU        BHH
```

I did try to use `dcast` and `melt` but didn't workout for me, I am new to R, please help

Comment: R is not fond of duplicate column names. Can I ask what you are trying to achieve by formatting your column this way?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another proposition:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
       check.names = FALSE,
              type = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
        `function` = c("AXX", "AZZ", "BXX", "BUU"),
             class = c("AYY", "AUU", "BYY", "BHH")
      )

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number())

df <- split(df, df$id)
df <- map(df, select, -id)
df <- reduce(df, cbind)
names(df) <- gsub("[.]*\\d$", "", names(df))
```

However, I'm afraid having columns with the same name can be problematic in future.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're expecting ?

```
library(dplyr)

my_df <- data.frame("type" = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C"),
                "function1" = c("AXX", "AZZ", "BXX", "BUU", "CCC"),
                "class1" = c("AYY", "AUU", "BYY", "BHH", "CCC"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_df <- my_df %>% group_by(type) %>% mutate(My_id = cur_group_id())
my_base <- my_df %>% group_by(type) %>% filter(row_number() == 1)
my_other <- my_df %>% group_by(type) %>% filter(row_number() != 1)
my_base <- left_join(x = my_base, y = my_other, by = "My_id")
colnames(my_base) <- gsub(pattern = "\\.x$|\\.y$", replacement = "", x = colnames(my_base))
my_base <- my_base[, -which(colnames(my_base) == "My_id")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all the (yet) proposed solutions do only work if the type elements are only once or twice in the data.frame. I'm not sure if this is always the case in your data, therefore I added an if-condition to my solution.

```
result = NULL
dataCount <- max(as.data.frame(table(data$type))[,2])
if (dataCount <= 2){
  data1 <- data[duplicated(data$type),]
  data2 <- data[!duplicated(data$type),]
  result <- merge(data2, data1, by="type", all.x=T)
} 
>result
      type function..x class.x function..y class.y
    1    A         AXX     AYY         AZZ     AUU
    2    B         BXX     BYY         BUU     BHH
```

If you want to create then the data.frame you've asked for you can simply do:

```
result$type.y <- result$type
result <- result[,c(1,2,3,6,4,5)]
names(result) <- unlist(lapply(1:ncol(result), function(x) {strsplit(names(result)[x], "[.]")[[1]][1] }))

> result
  type function class type function class
1    A      AXX   AYY    A      AZZ   AUU
2    B      BXX   BYY    B      BUU   BHH
```

However, in general, I would recommend avoiding using `function` as a column name (e.g. use `function2use` instead) because it is a build-in name in R, and use the naming from the merge output e.g. class.x and class.y instead of using the same column name twice.